# JS two if's statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wrote a javascript code which if you are browsing with Firefox and if the window is resized to pop up an alert box. However, my knowledge is not enough to see where is the mistake in the code I wrote. If someone can help me I will be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
$('FirefoxChecker').ready(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) && (window.onresize){
        alert("Some text here");
    };
});
```

Comment: Window.onresize is a event.. Why don't you check if its Firefox inside your window.onresize event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `window.onresize` is an event not property.

**Edit:** As mentioned by *EasyBB* in comments, `onresize` is a property of the window but its in initial value is `null` unless we define one. It expects a `value` to be an `eventHandler` which will be invoked when `resize` event takes place.

Try this:

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
    alert("Some text here");
  }
};
```

To invoke something when `resize` is done, try this:

```js
var timeOut;
window.onresize = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
      alert("Some text here");
    }
  }, 200);
};
```

Comment: How is this different from my comments??

Comment: @Reddy not sure, but it `onresize` is still a property none the less. `window.hasOwnProperty("onresize");` returns true. the MSDN classifies it as a property as well.

Comment: @RayonDabre , Thank you very much for your help. It worked. I hope I am not getting too insolent but is there a way to to show this alert when the user finally stopped expanding and collapsing the browser window?

Comment: Keep on listening `onresize` and put `setTImeout` in handler. Check the edit!

Comment: @RayonDabre, Thank you very much for the help. I will try that now.

Answer (score 4):

Incorrectly formatting your conditional statement

```
$('FirefoxChecker').ready(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0 && window.onresize){
        alert("Some text here");
    }//; no semicolon
});
```

You can have as many conditions as you want in one statement for example

```
if( condition1 && conditio2 || condition3) { }
```

Your initial statement was a disconnection between eachother.

```
if( condition1) && (condition2) {} //is incorrect of course
```

YET! We can do something like this and what it does is clean the statement up or make the statement more accurate.

```
             //group1                       //group2
 if( (condition1 && condition2) || (condition3 && condition1) ) 
   1 2                        2    3                        3 1
```

I've added numbers below and they correspond to each parenthesis that it belongs to.

As others have said `window.onresize` is not a testable property, but you get that and hopefully can move forward on that. We can test `onresize` though like so

```
if("onresize" in window) {}
```

Comment: Also I think you might point out that he had an extra `(`  , the one before window.

Comment: Yes this is true. I'll make a note of that